# IOS Opening Swift based view controller from objective-c view controller .m file

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, viewcontroller

I have a Facebook login screen based on Objective-C code and xib file for interface. After generating the access token, I want to open the next screen that is based on Swift. Anyone please help me how do I open a swift based view controller from objective-c view controller. When I write the name of view controller, xcode never recognizes. Googled since yesterday but got no success.
Please help :)

Comment: Have you configured your project to detect swift files? If not, then please check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24002369/how-to-call-objective-c-code-from-swift also this http://mobiforge.com/design-development/using-objective-c-and-swift-together-ios-apps

Comment: @SohilR.Memon: thanks a lot, now xcode is able to recognise my swift file after importing <myproject-Swift.h>, but still I can switch to that view controller: the code is not doing anything.

here is the code im using to switch to that view controller:
'ViewController *directionViewController = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"viewController"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:directionViewController animated:TRUE];'

Comment: have you imported your swift file in bridgingheader.h file?

Comment: the one I want to open? How do I import it? #import "ViewController.swift"?

Comment: its creating error in ViewController class